# parameter value missing '#' in action

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am simply calling as

```
window.location = '../MyController/MyAction?campId=' + campId + '&campName=' + campName;
```

and in action am receiving it as

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult MyAction(int campId, string campName)
    {
```

...

my problem is from js am passing the campName value 'Anish#' but in action am only getting 'Anish'. value after # in not getting at action. how can i solve this.

any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to URL encode all your parameters using the [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) javascript function:

```
window.location.href = '../MyController/MyAction?' + 
    'campId=' + encodeURIComponent(campId) + 
    '&campName=' + encodeURIComponent(campName);
```

or if you are using jQuery you could use the [`$.param()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) function which will take care of properly URL encoding your parameter values:

```
var parameters = $.param({ campId: campId, campName: campName });
window.location.href = '../MyController/MyAction?' + parameters;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `#` character is used to separate the client portion of a URL from the server portion.

E.g.

```
http://www.example.com/where?this_is=a_param#this_can_be_an_anchor_name
```

I don't believe that the client-side URL fragment (i.e. data after the #) is ever returned to the browser.

If what you're trying to do is return a `#` as part of a parameter value then URL Encoding the parameter value as discussed in Darin's answer will solve this for you.